# How rails compare with datetime with timestamp

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datetime

I have a code like this

```
  if user.created_at >= 1563724800
    do sth
  end
```

which user.created_at is definitely > 1563724800. But it still return false. I have to use `user.created_at.to_i >= 1563724800` to get what I'm expect. So I wonder how it works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So far as I understand you should do like this (to compare an integer with DateTime convert it to integer also)-

```
  if user.created_at.to_i >= 1563724800
    do sth
  end
```

Or you should compare reversely (convert an integer to DateTime)

```
  if user.created_at >= Time.at(1563724800)
    do sth
  end
```

[time.to_i => int](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#M000257)  time as an integer number of seconds since epoch.

[Time.at(seconds) => time](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#M000251) => new time object with the given number of seconds

Comment: Yes, I know I have to convert it to integer now. But I wonder what it do when I compare them directly. Why it return false

Comment: @ThanksSirAlex This is due to `created_at` is an instance of `Time`  and `1563724800` is an instance of `Integer` and `nil` is returned if the two objects are incomparable and in ruby `nil` is treated as a `false` also. Hopefully, that makes sense. for more details you can follow along https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.3/Time.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E

Comment: I don't think so. When I tried to compare them by using `user.created_at <=> 1563724800` it return `-1` not `nil`, so somehow ruby think it's smaller than the int value but not they are incomparable. So that's not understandable. So ruby must did sth when comparing them.

Comment: @ThanksSirAlex Hmm, This is a bit advanced topic so far, in short, I'm trying to explain it as every class in ruby includes Comparable module based on that comparison operator work, that is > or >=  or < or <= ..etc are overridden methods in Time class, and it works accordingly as <=> returns value.